# AWS get response as data, not JSON (for using with Codable)

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

Not familiar enough with AWS, but I have some `Codable` models I need to initialize from AWS. I'm getting `JSON` result from `AWSTask.result` (which is `AnyObject`). I'm trying to avoid creating `Data` from `Dictionaty` and back to a `struct` (to be able to use `Codable`).
I tied to use `AWSNetworkingHTTPResponseInterceptor`, but it was never got called and I couldn't find any example of using it.

```swift
self.getGatewayClient { (apiGatewayClient: AWSAPIGatewayClient?) in
    
    let queryParameters = ...
    let headerParameters = ...
    
    apiGatewayClient?.invokeHTTPRequest(
        "GET",
        urlString: "/path",
        pathParameters: [:],
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        headerParameters: headerParameters,
        body: nil,
        responseClass: nil
    ).continueWith { (task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        
        if let data = task... { // Get response as Data type??
            
        }
        
        if let result = task.result as? [String: Any] {
            // Thanks, but I have a Codable, so I'll just take the data thank you.
        }
        
        return task
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-json-into-swift-objects-using-codable ?

Comment: @koen Thanks, but I wrote "I'm trying to avoid creating Data from Dictionaty". Notice that: "`let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)`", is doing something similar to the operation I'm trying to avoid. Also, I get a `Dictionary` from AWS, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

AWS's `AWSAPIGatewayClient` has two functions, one is: `invokeHTTPRequest` (which was what was used). There is another one called `invoke`, which returns data. It takes a `AWSAPIGatewayRequest` request:

```swift
func someTask(completion: @escaping (String?) -> ()) {
    self.getGatewayClient { (apiGatewayClient: AWSAPIGatewayClient?) in
        let request = AWSAPIGatewayRequest(httpMethod: "GET",
                                           urlString: "/path",
                                           queryParameters: queryParameters,
                                           headerParameters: headerParameters,
                                           httpBody: nil)
        apiGatewayClient?.invoke(request).continueOnSuccessWith { response in
            
            if let data = response.result?.responseData {
                // Init Codable using data
            }
        }
    }
}
```